# Should I create a new version when I trying to add a field in CRD?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

If I want to add a field in a CRD(without change any exist field), Should I do it by create a new version?

If I should create a new version, then what's the disadvantages of directly modifying the original version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the **[blog](https://faun.dev/c/stories/dineshparvathaneni/kubernetes-crd-versioning-for-operator-developers/)** written by **Dinesh Parvathaneni**, you can validate the points as mentioned below:

CRDs are similar to K8s built-in types and the expectation for operator developers is to follow the same guidelines when it comes to their versioning.

- > Adding a **required new field** or removing a field is a **backward incompatible change** to the API. This makes all the old versions
  > immediately unusable. So don’t make backward incompatible CRD API
  > changes.
- > If you want to still continue using the old versions they need to be updated with the **new field** as an **optional parameter** as K8s
  > doesn’t add a required field, instead adds an optional field with a
  > default value.

  > **Example**: when a new field is added, the new version of the operator would still behave as the old version when the new field is
  > not provided in user input. This is more like a **feature flag** for
  > the new features in the operator.
- > CRD can define multiple versions of the custom resource. A version can be marked as served or not served and only one version can be
  > used as a storage version in **etcd**.
- > If there is **schema difference** across versions, conversion **webhooks** are needed to convert between versions when necessary.

Hope the above information is useful to you.